# How to get the index and max value of an array in one shot?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Given a list of integer elements, how to get the max value and it's index in one shot. If there is more than one element with same max value, returning index of any one of them is fine.

For example:

```
// Initialize list of integer
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(5, 8, 3, 2);
// To get max value
Optional<Integer> maxVal = intList.stream().reduce(Integer::max);
// But how could I also get its index without iterating the array again?
```

If I have to do it only once, I could just sort the array and get the first or last one (based on sort order). However, I would like to see how we can do it without sorting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally, if you need an index, you’ll have to stream over the indices. Then, the task becomes straight-forward:

```
List<Integer> intArr = Arrays.asList(5, 8, 3, 2);
IntStream.range(0, intArr.size())
  .reduce((a,b)->intArr.get(a)<intArr.get(b)? b: a)
  .ifPresent(ix->System.out.println("Index "+ix+", value "+intArr.get(ix)));
```

a more elegant solution, which unfortunately incorporates boxing overhead is

```
IntStream.range(0, intArr.size())
  .boxed().max(Comparator.comparing(intArr::get))
  .ifPresent(ix->System.out.println("Index "+ix+", value "+intArr.get(ix)));
```

Comment: What's the significance of boxed?

Comment: @SriniK I believe that's because you can't have a `Comparator<int>`. But again, I could be wrong since I am still a bit new to Java 8.

Comment: @Chetan Kinger: you are right, there is no `Comparator<int>` and so, `IntStream` doesn’t offer a `max(Comparator)` method, but only a `max()` which doesn’t help here (same applies to `min` or `sorted`, `IntStream` supports natural order only).

Comment: @Holger Why not directly use `intArr.stream().max(comparator)` instead?

Comment: @Chetan Kinger: that’s what the question is all about; the OP wants the *index* of the max value. If you only care for the value, `intArr.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder())`, which isn’t different to the OP’s `intList.stream().reduce(Integer::max)`, would be enough. But it won’t give you the index.

Comment: Was wondering if the `reduce` solution does an O(n^2) (quadratic) traversal? Meaning, does the reduce compare all numbers to the others? From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), it seams to compare only against one element - the accumulated result.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: it’s an `O(n)` operation. It’s not specified which elements will be processed, as the reduction function is required to be associative, so it may do `((e1 op e2) op e3) op e4` or `(e1 op e2) op (e3 op e4)`, but you see, in either case, the number of operations is the same. The `max` operation is just a special, built-in reduction, having exactly the same time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using third-party code, my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library provides some shortcuts for this task:

```
List<Integer> intArr = Arrays.asList(5, 8, 3, 2);
IntStreamEx.ofIndices(intArr)
           .maxBy(intArr::get)
           .ifPresent(ix->System.out.println("Index "+ix+", value "+intArr.get(ix)));
```

Internally it's close to the first solution provided by @Holger (no boxing).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is currently any solution that's equally as fast as iterating manually:

```
int maxValueIndex = 0;
Integer maxValue = null;
for (int i = 0, n = intList.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    Integer value = intList.get(i);
    if (value == null || maxValue != null && value <= maxValue)
        continue;
    maxValue = value;
    maxValueIndex = i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In java8 you can [execute streams in parallel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#executing_streams_in_parallel)

```
Integer[] intArr= {1,2,6,2,234,3,54,6,4564,456};

IntStream.range(0, intArr.length-1).parallel().
                reduce((a,b)->intArr[a]<intArr[b]? b: a).
                ifPresent(ix -> System.out.println("Index: " + ix + ", value: " + intArr[ix]));
```