# Java 8: Find index of minimum value from a List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Say I have a list with elements `(34, 11, 98, 56, 43)`.

Using Java 8 streams, how do I find the index of the minimum element of the list (e.g. 1 in this case)?

I know this can be done easily in Java using `list.indexOf(Collections.min(list))`. However, I am looking at a Scala like solution where we can simply say `List(34, 11, 98, 56, 43).zipWithIndex.min._2` to get the index of minimum value.

Is there anything that can be done using streams or lambda expressions (say Java 8 specific features) to achieve the same result.

Note: This is just for learning purpose. I don't have any problem in using `Collections` utility methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the index and max value of an array in one shot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730861/how-to-get-the-index-and-max-value-of-an-array-in-one-shot)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;

int minIndex = IntStream.range(0,list.size()).boxed()
            .min(comparingInt(list::get))
            .get();  // or throw if empty list
```

As @TagirValeev mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31116669/3920048), you can avoid boxing by using `IntStream#reduce` instead of `Stream#min`, but at the cost of obscuring the intent:

```
int minIdx = IntStream.range(0,list.size())
            .reduce((i,j) -> list.get(i) > list.get(j) ? j : i)
            .getAsInt();  // or throw
```

Comment: Yes this is a nice one +1. I was focused on the `zipWithIndex` case, but this might be the idiom way to solve this. I would just use `orElse(-1)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
int indexMin = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> new SimpleEntry<>(i, list.get(i)))
                .min(comparingInt(SimpleEntry::getValue))
                .map(SimpleEntry::getKey)
                .orElse(-1);
```

If the list is a random access list, `get` is a constant time operation. The API lacks of a standard tuple class, so I used the `SimpleEntry` from the `AbstractMap` class as a substitute.

So `IntStream.range` generates a stream of indexes from the list from which you map each index to its corresponding value. Then you get the minimum element by providing a comparator on the values (the ones in the list). From there you map the `Optional<SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>>` to an `Optional<Integer>` from which you get the index (or -1 if the optional is empty).

As an aside, I would probably use a simple for-loop to get the index of the minimum value, as your combination of `min` / `indexOf` does 2 passes over the list.

You might also be interested to check [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda (java.util.stream.Streams.zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip)

Comment: Thanks @Alexis, seems to be more complicated than the simple usage of `Collections` or 'Scala`s implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's two possible solutions using my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```
int idx = IntStreamEx.ofIndices(list).minBy(list::get).getAsInt();
```

Or:

```
int idx = EntryStream.of(list).minBy(Entry::getValue).get().getKey();
```

The second solution internally is very close to one proposed by @AlexisC. The first one is probably the fastest as it does not use boxing ([internally](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/854423ec9a8dd5b8c7d126b862eda1a3a07d3700/src/main/java/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.java#L683) it's a reduce operation).

Without using third-party code @Misha's answer looks the best for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is for learning purposes, let's try to find a solution that doesn't just somehow use a stream, but actually works on the stream of our list. We also don't want to assume random access.

So, there are two ways to get a non-trivial result out of a stream: `collect` and `reduce`. [Here](https://ideone.com/1af1EQ) is a solution that uses a collector:

```
class Minimum {
    int index = -1; 
    int range = 0;
    int value;

    public void accept(int value) {
        if (range == 0 || value < this.value) {
            index = range;
            this.value = value;
        }
        range++;
    }

    public Minimum combine(Minimum other) {
        if (value > other.value) {
            index = range + other.index;
            value = other.value;
        }
        range += other.range;
        return this;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
}

static Collector<Integer, Minimum, Integer> MIN_INDEX = new Collector<Integer, Minimum, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Supplier<Minimum> supplier() {
            return Minimum::new;
        }
        @Override
        public BiConsumer<Minimum, Integer> accumulator() {
            return Minimum::accept;
        }
        @Override
        public BinaryOperator<Minimum> combiner() {
           return Minimum::combine;
        }
        @Override
        public Function<Minimum, Integer> finisher() {
            return Minimum::getIndex;
        }
        @Override
        public Set<Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }
    };
```

Writing a collectors creates an annoying amount of code, but it can be easily generalized to support any comparable value. Also, calling the collector looks very idiomatic:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(4,3,7,1,5,2,9);
int minIndex = list.stream().collect(MIN_INDEX);
```

If we change the `accept` and `combine` methods to always return a new `Minimum` instance (ie. if we make `Minimum` immutable), we can also use `reduce`:

```
int minIndex = list.stream().reduce(new Minimum(), Minimum::accept, Minimum::combine).getIndex();
```

I sense large potential for parallelization in this one.

Comment: Quite interesting solution. First I thought it will not work for parallel streams, but seems it will. Note that you can use `Collector.of(Minimum::new, Minimum::accept, Minimum::combine, Minimum::getIndex)` instead of defining an anonymous class.

Comment: This approach has the advantage of not requiring the list to be random access friendly.  Note that `combine` method should correctly handle the case of `other` being empty.  `Collector` javadoc specifically requires that for parallel-friendliness as the "identity constraint".  It doesn't say anything about handling the case of `this` being empty and `other` not empty, but it seems prudent to handle that as well.

Comment: @Misha, yes, it has some minor problems, but I like the idea. Btw it works quite fast, on some tests it even outperforms my `IntStreamEx.minBy`. I [committed](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/commit/86703a8b787e4769766c99112db5ba42d75ac3c4) a fixed version, probably will include it in my lib.