# Java 8 - Retrieve position in the list via stream

Tags: java, java-stream

In a stream of a list of Integer like this `list.stream().max((a,b)->a+b).get();` i can only retrieve the highest value, i wanted to retrieve the position in the list of the highest value, how can i do it ?

Comment: A `Stream` does not record any kind of index; you can do this via a hack, but really a good old fashioned for loop walking according to indices is your best bet here. Also, the argument to your .max() is really bizarre; what is it that you want to do?

Comment: Just look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116190/java-8-find-index-of-minimum-value-from-a-list

Comment: Yes i got it how to do that without stream, just as a curiosity, doesn't the lambda in max, just iterate through the values and check the max, if not how am i supposed to write that ?