# Get max and maxIndex of sum of two lists of floats in java fast

Tags: java, android, java-stream, lightweight-stream-api

I am trying to calculate the max sum pair of two lists with a faster way than what i've managed below, using ["lightweight streams"](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API):

```
 List<Float> pairsSum = new ArrayList<>();
 // Get the list with all the sums
 Stream.range(0, list1.size())
          .forEach(i -> pairsSum.add(list1.get(i) + list2.get(i)));
 // Get the index of the max pair
 maxIndex = pairsSum.indexOf(Stream.of(pairsSum).max(Double::compare).orElse(0f));
```

Comment: And where is problem or question?

Comment: Maybe the pairsSum list is not needed and the calculation of sum and max could be done on the fly, but i couldn't figure it out, so i'm generally asking for an optimization on the above code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730861/how-to-get-the-index-and-max-value-of-an-array-in-one-shot ?

Comment: @DominicFischer That's about one array, not the sum of two arrays

Comment: Oops but you could still adapt that solution to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short solution is to use an `IntStream` and the `reduce()` method:

```
int maxIndex = IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
        .reduce((i1, i2) -> list1.get(i1) + list2.get(i1) < list1.get(i2) + list2.get(i2) ? i2 : i1)
        .orElse(-1);
```

If you want the index, both values and the sum, you can use a custom `Result` class:

```
public static class Result {
    private int index;
    private float left;
    private float right;
    private float sum;
    // constructor and getters
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Result max = IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> new Result(i, list1.get(i), list2.get(i), list1.get(i) + list2.get(i)))
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Result::getSum))
        .orElse(null);
```

The time complexity in both cases is *O(n)*.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Float> pairsSum = new ArrayList<>(repLeftForces.size());
// Get the list with all the sums
int maxIndex = -1;
float max = 0F;
for (int i =0; i < repLeftForces.size(); ++i) {
    float sum = list1.get(i) + list2.get(i);
    //pairsSum.add(sub);
    if (maxIndex == -1 || sum > max) {
        maxIndex = i;
        max = sum;
    }
 }
```

The pairsSum list is not needed actually. But when used, the actual size is known in advance.

As one wants to do a *reduce* too for a maximum, and receive additionally the maxIndex, best would be a classical loop instead of using a Stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the list of sums in one line by mapping the streams (I did add line breaks for legibility):

```
    //made some example lists
    List<Float> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Float[]{1F, 2F, 3F});
    List<Float> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Float[]{2F, 3F, 4F});

    // Get the list with all the sums
    List<Float> sums = list1.stream()
            .map( f -> (list2.get(list1.lastIndexOf(f)) + f ) )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Get the index of the max pair
    int maxIndex = sums.indexOf(sums.stream().max(Float::compareTo).get());
```

Just stream the first list, and `.map` it (map is like a foreach but returns a result for each list item).

*What's happening in the map:*
for each item it finds the highest index for the current value `f` in list 1. That'll be the index of the current item in the first list. Then it gets the value for this index in the second list. `list2.get(list1.lastIndexOf(f))`. So now you add the current value `f` to that. This way, for the full length of list 1 you are outputting the sum of the two values that share the same index.

Then you just need to `.collect` them back into a list.

Finally to find the max index, I would take the exact same approach you did.

Comment: That solution is not faster than the solution provided by OP, because `List.indexOf()` has a time complexity of _O(n). So your solution has a time complexity of _O(n²)_.